# input of date in html5 with a prompt for today

Tags: html, date

**Part 1**

I have tried the answer given in "6982692/html5-input-type-date-default-value-to-today" but cannot get it to work for me.

In my .html as the only line in a "div" within a "form" I have:

```
<input type="date" id="theDate">
```

There are other divs in that form for other parameters.

And in my .js I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var date = new Date();

    var day = date.getDate();
    var mth = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = date.getFullYear();

    if (mth < 10) mth = "0" + mth;
    if (day < 10) day = "0" + day;

    var ThisOne = year + "-" + mth + "-" + day;       
    $("#theDate").attr("value", ThisOne);
});
```

I am expecting the date input box to be populated with today's date.  What is displayed is "dd.mm.yyyy".  And that is what is displayed without the extra code.

Either way a display box of days in the current month appears on selecting the right hand arrow of the date input box.

I expect today's date will be "correct" more often than not.

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

**Part 2**

To assist with testing I would like display the date
and other values I actually select.

I have tried "p ..." without success

While I have some texts on HTML4 and am looking online 
I cannot see a solution I can apply.

I would like to see my values with the HTML halted until 
I have read them.  (It goes on to do something else as 
soon as all parameter elements in the form are got.)

Comment: I have formatted your code a bit better using the `{}` button on the toolbar to indent it all so that it all gets correctly highlighted as code. Also please note that rather than having a "Part 1" and "Part 2", it may be better to post as two separate questions.

Comment: this seems to work for me... http://jsfiddle.net/9x6enpz4/

Comment: Two questions: One, why did you have two questions in one question? Two, why didn't you directly link to the question you're talking about?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2466684/diego-romero - I am new to all of this and am even having trouble starting a new line.   I note to the left of your code boxes an option "onLoad".  Is this something that should be set up earlier in the .html script?   Also, where does the JavaScript sit - in the .html file or the .js file?